# Calculating the mutual information between two random vectors returns the same value

Tags: python, mutual-information

I want to calculate the mutual information between two numpy vectors:

```py
>>>from sklearn.metrics.cluster import mutual_info_score
>>>import numpy as np

>>>a, b = np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10)
>>>mutual_info_score(a, b)
1.6094379124341005

>>>a, b = np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10)
>>>mutual_info_score(a, b)
1.6094379124341005
```

As you can see, although I updated `a` and `b`, it returned the same value. Then I tried another example:

```py
>>>a = np.array([167.52523295,  73.2904335 ,  98.61953303, 152.17297007,
       211.01341451, 327.72296346, 356.60500081,  43.9371432 ,
       119.09474284, 125.20180842])

>>>b = np.array([280.9287028 , 131.76304983, 176.0277832 , 188.56630096,
       229.09811401, 228.47200012, 617.67000122,  52.7211511 ,
       125.95361582, 148.55247447])

>>>mutual_info_score(a, b)
2.302585092994046


>>>a = np.array([ 6.71381009,  1.43607653,  3.78729242, -4.75706796, -3.81281173,
        3.23440092, 10.84495625, -0.19646145,  4.09724507, -0.13858104])

>>>b = np.array([ 4.25330873,  3.02197642, -3.2833848 ,  0.41855662, -3.74693531,
        0.7674982 , 11.36459148,  0.64636462,  0.51817262,  1.65318943])

>>>mutual_info_score(a, b)
2.302585092994046
```

Why? Look at the difference between those numbers. Why it returns the same value? More importantly, **how do I calculate the MI between two vectors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you will obtain different numbers each time you run the cell. Here, you're utilizing a method that is suitable for measuring the quality of clustering results!
Let's quickly jump into the principal material. For observing the mutual information (MI) between two vectors (or even several vectors), you can use the [`mutual_info_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression) function (as described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_f_test_vs_mi.html)):

```
In [1]: from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression

In [2]: a, target = np.random.rand(10, 3)+300, np.random.rand(10)

In [3]: mi = mutual_info_regression(a, target)

In [4]: mi
Out[4]: array([0.18373016, 0.19396825, 0.09634921])
```

In the above, I calculated the MI between each feature of the `a` with the `target`! E.g., the MI between the first feature and the `target` is ~0.184. There are various ways to calculate MI between variables, e.g.:

- estimate mutual information (MI) with histograms. E.g., code:

  ```
  from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score

  def MI(x, y, bins):
      c_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins)[0]
      mi = mutual_info_score(None, None, contingency=c_xy)
      return mi
  ```

  The challenge is finding a suitable value for the number of `bins` here. [[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/181195/340393)]
- based on entropy estimation from k-nearest neighbors' distances (`mutual_info_regression` is based on this approach)
- etc.

P.S. Reading [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ryanholbrook/mutual-information) document is worthwhile.